# Interchange day and Month in a date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column containing dates and in that some cell values are having values like " Due on Date". I have written a app script code that if a cell value contains "Due on" it will be copied to another column,else copied to different column.But on running I found that cells having "due on " on running the date and month are interchanged. for eg: if a cell contains "Due on 08/02/2022(dd/MM/yyyy)" is changed to "02/08/2022(MM/dd/yyyy)". Is there any method to retain the same date format.Here is the sample code:

```
    function addYear(ss){
     var value =  ss.getDataRange().getValues();
     value.shift();
     for(var i=value.length-1;i>=0;i--){
     var chn = value[i];
     if(chn[2]!="NA"){
     var rdate= new Date(chn[2]);
     var dat=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(rdate), "GMT+5:30", "dd-MM-yyyy");
     var mat= chn[2].toString();
     if(mat.match(/Due on/)){
      var d1= mat.toString().replace("Due on", "");
      var ds = new Date(dat);
      ss.getRange("C"+(i+2)).setValue("Valid till "+Utilities.formatDate(ds, "GMT+5:30", "dd-MMMM-yyyy"));
      }
    else{
     var ds = new Date(chn[2]);
     var yearadc = ds.getFullYear();
     var monthadc = ds.getMonth(); 
     var dayadc = ds.getDate();
     var adc = new Date(yearadc + 1, monthadc, dayadc-1);
     ss.getRange("C"+(i+2)).setValue("Valid till "+ Utilities.formatDate(adc, "GMT+5:30", "dd-MMMM-yyyy"));
   }
  }
```

I have made some changes to the code but if the day is greater than 12,the code reads as 01/01/1970. I am attaching a image relevant to this code.
[image: spreadsheet copy]
I want to retain the original format as dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: in your code you have var month is getDay, and var day is getMonth, then pubdate is year, day, month. spend more time checking your code.

Comment: @Mr Shane I interchanged day amd month so that I can get the original format but still I am getting as mm dd yyyy rather than ddmmyyyy. Note : actual input values are in ddmmyyyy

Comment: are BOTH the spreadsheet AND apps script using the same timezone? App Script's time zone can be checked by using the Legacy editor and clicking `File > Project properties > Time Zone` from the menu above the script editor.
Google Sheets time zone can be checked by clicking `File > Spreadsheet settings`

Comment: @ Mr Shane The issue still persists even after resolving: 08/02/2022 is shown as august 2 instead of February 8. and 15/01/2022 is shown as 1 january 1970.

Comment: This issue may originate on the columns having different formats. Please check that configuration. If that doesn't help, please share a public copy of your Sheet.

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron I have attached the image and made some changes to the code .